# Symmetric relation proof

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, relations

Prove that the following relation is symmetric:
For all $x,y\in\Bbb N$, $xRy$ iff $x+y$ is even.

My attempt:

Assume $x,y$ are in $\Bbb N$, and $x+y$ is even. Since $x+y$ is even, then $x+y=2a$ for some integer $a\in\Bbb Z$… and that is where I get stuck.

How do I get $y+x=2a$ from there?

Thanks!

Comment: Commutativity of addition of x and y    !!

Comment: $y+x=x+y$, because addition is commutative.

Comment: Sorry, but we haven't learned about that yet in class. Is there another way?

Comment: @YRUG What are you allowed to use? Associativity? Cancellation?

Comment: If you haven't learned that addition is commutative (a + b = b + a) then, no, I don't think there is any way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x + y = y + x.

if x + y is even, then y+ x is even because x + y = x + y.

====

Okay, we can't know commutivity.

If x + y = e; e even.  Then

x + y - y = e -y

x = e - y

x - x = e - y - x

0 = e - (y + x)

y + x = e - (y + x) + (y + x) = e + 0 = e.

But that assumes we know of distributive and inverses.

Comment: in the comments YRUG mentions not being able to use commutative property of addition.

Comment: Good point.  But if we don't know addition is commutative then what *do* we know of addition.

Comment: Probably that it's closed under addition... other than that your guess is as good as mine. I added a comment above to request more detail

Answer (score 0):

We know that the sum of two integers is even if the individual are both even or odd.  Remember, odd plus = even and even plus even = odd and odd plus odd is odd.

So our numbers can either be expressed as x=2n y=2m or as x=2n+1 and y=2m+1. Once you have this it is a simple plug and chug of the two cases to show that it works both ways.
$x+y=$even $\Rightarrow x=2n, y=2m$ or $x=2n+1 y=2m+1$. If we take $y+x$ then it is either $y+x=2m+2n=2(m+n)$ which is even or we have $y+x=2m+1+2n+1=2m+2n+2=2(n+m+1)$ which is also even. Therefore our relationship is symmetric.

Cheers!

Comment: You do not need any field properties except distribution to prove the initial statement if you don't have it. Just take the sum of evens, odds and even/odd.

Comment: "We know that the sum of two integers is even if the individual are both even or odd."  How do we know that?  Can we know that If we don't know addition is commutative?

Comment: Assume we have even+even then we have $2n+2m=2(n+m)$ which is even. The proof follows similarly for the other cases. All you need is distribution.